Solve a scheduling problem with simulated annealing
I have this following simplified scheduling problem:
$$\sum_{i\in I}^{}\sum_{d\in D}^{}\sum_{j\in J}^{}c_{idj}\cdot x_{idj} \tag{1}$$
$$s.t.$$
$$\sum_{i\in I}^{}x_{ijd}\geq D_{jd}\quad\forall j,d \tag{2}$$
$$\sum_{j\in J}^{}x_{ijd}\leq 1\quad\forall i,d \tag{3}$$
where $I$ are the worker, $D$ the days and $J$ the shifts. $x_{idj}$ is the shift assignment, $c_{idj}$ the costs and $D_{dj}$ the demand. Obviously this problem can be solved instantly using solver such as Gurobi but I stated this model for simplification reasons.
How can I solve such a model with simulated annealing?
Since I only have a fitness function, I have to add the constraints to the objective function. How do I do that? How would the function look like and what is the general rule if I want to add further constraints?
I want to implement it in Python.

I would not move constraints into the objective function.  You'll need to create a heuristic to give you a feasible schedule, then when defining neighborhood moves you will need to do so to preserve feasibility (the preferred approach), or otherwise generate many neighboring solutions until you have a feasible one.

Look at the first two chapters of this book "Handbook of Metaheuristics":
https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-91086-4

Also, there's this original paper on the topic: https://www.cs.amherst.edu/ccm/cs34/papers/jobshop171189.pdf
